# Android Start a Countdown Timer onPreExecute and End onPostExecute

Tags: android, timer

I am trying to show a countdown timer onPreExecute and End the timer onPostExecute.I have below code which is working fine onPreExecute but I am not finding any way how to dismiss this timer on onPostExecute.Below is my timer code

```
            new CountDownTimer(240000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    String time=""+String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
                    Toast.makeText(context, time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onFinish() {

                    Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(i);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "oops! Pls check your net connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create A Global Variable of Timer

```
CountDownTimer mTimer = null;
```

on PreExecute() write

```
@Override
protected  void onPreExecute()
{
  mTimer = new CountDownTimer(240000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String time=""+String.format("%d min, %d sec",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
                Toast.makeText(context, time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onFinish() {

                Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(context, "oops! Pls check your net connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }.start();
}
```

now on postExecute() write

```
@Override
protected  void onPostExecute()
{
  mTimer.cancel();
}
```